# Where to create session table in rails 3.2.8 app with engines?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-engines

In a rails 3.2.8 app, we create a rails mountable engine `authentify` for user authentication. Our question is where to create session table, in rails app (main app) or in engine `authentify`?

If we create session table in rails app, then accessing session variable would be the same as regular rails app with session[:variable_name]. We tested creating session tables in engine authentify and `session[:user_id]` defined in authentify could not be accessed with `session[:user_id]` in other rails engine.  `authentify_session[:user_id]` is not working as well.